# how can I combine button with input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, w3.css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<body>

<form id="image-form" action="#" class="w3-container w3-border w3-margin-top">
    <input id="mediaCapture" type="file" accept="image/*,capture=camera" >
    <button id="submitImage" title="Add an image" class="w3-btn w3-dark-grey w3-left">
        <i class="material-icons">image</i>
    </button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The `<input>` creates a "browse..." button with text "No file selected"

I also have a image icon as a button.

How can I substitute the icon button for browse button?

Once I click the icon button, it will open up the directory to let me choose image.

Thanks for any help.

I am using w3.css framework.

Comment: Please create a Plunker or JSFiddle example of your code. Thanks.

Comment: This link is bootstrap specific but you may be able to adapt it to your needs:  https://www.abeautifulsite.net/whipping-file-inputs-into-shape-with-bootstrap-3

Comment: make your input file's visibility zero and place it over the button using absolute positioning. Also set its dimensions same as the button's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the `input` element's display property to `hidden`, you can still trigger the file selection process by clicking on the `label` element. Place your icon inside the `label` and style accordingly.

Make sure the `for` attribute of the `label` element matches the `id` of the file `input`

```
<style>
  .hidden {display:none;}
</style>
<label for="mediaCapture">
  <i class="material-icons">image</i>
</label>
<input type="file" class="hidden" id="mediaCapture">
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `input` element's display property to hidden, then setting the `button` element's click event to trigger the `input` element's click event.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<body>

<form id="image-form" action="#" class="w3-container w3-border w3-margin-top">
    <input id="mediaCapture" type="file" accept="image/*,capture=camera" style="display: none;">
    <button id="submitImage" title="Add an image" class="w3-btn w3-dark-grey w3-left">
        <i class="material-icons">image</i>
    </button>
</form>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#submitImage').on('click', function(){
        $('#mediaCapture').trigger('click');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```